# Share Hibernate 2LC when using the same entities from different war files?

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly, infinispan

An application I am working on consists of different parts providing different types of functionalities. The code for each functionality should be deployable as a separate war file because not all functionalities will be required in every deployment. For example, I want to deploy: myapp-admin.war, myapp-dashboard.war and myapp-batch.war.

However, the functionalities all use the same data model and should access the same data source. Thus, I have created a myapp-jpa.jar which includes the entity definitions and the persistence.xml and is included in all three of the above war files.

Now, I want to enable the hibernate second level cache (2LC).

However, I am not sure how to configure Hibernate / JBoss / Infinispan to make sure that all three wars (when deployed on the same server) actually share the same cache instances. By default, JBoss / Infinispan seem to start individual cache instances for each entity for each war file judging from the log messages on deployment:

```
INFO WFLYCLINF0002 Started myapp-admin.war#datasource.org.example.MyEntity cache from hibernate container
INFO WFLYCLINF0002 Started myapp-dashboard.war#datasource.org.example.MyEntity cache from hibernate container
INFO WFLYCLINF0002 Started myapp-batch.war#datasource.org.example.MyEntity cache from hibernate container
```

How can I make sure that the three war files actually share the same Infinispan cache instances?

EDIT:
I tried setting the configuration property hibernate.cache.region_prefix to force all caches to share the same prefix. However, now I Deployment sometimes fails with

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Caused by org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000453: Attempt to define configuration for cache org.example.MyEntity which already exists
```

Comment: You will probably have to configure the caches individually in the cache container of your standalone.xml but I never tried doing this. I would ask myself though, what is the lifecycle of each application when an entity class changes. If the answer is that all three applications need to be re-deployed, what is the point of having three WARs then? It's only going to consume more memory. So maybe think about doing a single deployment instead and try to solve the problem you were trying to solve by doing this, in a different way.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov: Thank you for the input! The reason for "splitting up" the app is mostly based on different use-cases which will be deployed to different environments (Part A of the application will only be used by group A of users and part B only by group B). Thus, I thought it would make sense to split the deployment to servers only accessible to group A respectively group B. However, it really seems that Hibernate / Java EE applications are not really meant to be deployed that way.

Comment: Well, you can do that, but you would have to implement the cache invalidation yourself.